# Scroll to a UILabel location within a UIScrollView

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

I was wondering if it is possible to scroll to the location of a UILabel that is located within a ScrollView. This is what I have tried so far but I can't get it to work. I'm also shifting the view when the user begins to edit a TextView, I'm not sure if that may be preventing this from working.

```
// Code to scroll to label location    
scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: scrollView.contentOffset.x, y: label.frame.origin.y), animated: true)

// Code to shift view up by height of keyboard
if view.frame.origin.y == 0 {
    view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardRect.height
}
```

Comment: You can use this class for keyboard management https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

Comment: What is `label`'s relation to `scrollView`? What do you mean by you "can't get it to work"? Does it move at all?

Comment: Try using `label.superview?.convertPoint(label.frame.origin, toView: scrollView).y` which will convert your label's origin to the scroll view's frame.

Comment: @SpartanEngr1297 Try:
 
scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: lableToScroll.frame.minY), animated: true)

For shifting the view when keypad appears, you could better use some library (e.g. https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager)